# toggle to work with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello and thank you in advance for anyone that helps.

I have a website I am building ([Example link](http://tinyurl.com/ptvbxkl)), I am trying to use icons when clicked to open up a lightbox (using fancybox). In the lightbox I have tabs to showcase images.

**The problem:** When the lightbox opens I want the icon originally clicked to be infront of the lightbox overlay background, so I attempted to code in a java toggle for the image to z-index:10000 on click and it works, but its not in sync with the click and not really working correctly, I need it to toggle if clicking out of the lightbox or clicking the icon again. So it needs to click in sync with the lightbox (fancybox) code. Is there a way to do this? or any other better ways to achieve this?

Here is what I have done so far:
http://tinyurl.com/ptvbxkl

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which should work:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-cpl").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
       if(!$(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
           $.fancybox.close();
           return false;
       }
    });
});
```

css:

```
.toggle-cpl {
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

And a working decision on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fcguo4ta/

As you are trying to show/hide on click of the icon, you should add the 'fancybox.close' event trigger to the icon element click as well.

For the z-index - there is no need to add !important flag and as the fancybox has transitions - it is better to keep z-index static for both 'expanded' and not-expanded statements

Comment: Yes that works great thank you so much! The only thing, if you click on the overlay while in lightbox to get out of it you have to click the icon twice to get back in, where as if I click the icon to get out it only needs 1 click to get back in. Is there a fix for that? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if its linked to the same issue but if I add more than one icon with different content, if clicked out of a lightbox by clicking the overylay, when you click the other icon it has both icons light up, if clicking icon to get out then this is not an issue.

Comment: Any further help at all? anyone know how I can get it all to sync up?